# how to return response of axios in async function

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I want to return the response of axios but get the console.log as undefined.

```
getFirstPageData();

async function getFirstPageData() {

    const res =  await getPageData(1) ;

    console.log("res--->", res);
}

async function getPageData(page_num){

  let pageNum = page_num;
  console.log("page_num" , pageNum);

  let path =    "https://......"

  axios.get(path).then(
    (response) => {
        var result = response.data;
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
}
```

Is this a problem in await or async. any way returning this response.

Comment: Your `getPageData` doesnt return anything, hence the undefined. The `return` you use inside axios is specific to your arrow function `response => .... return result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to return the promise that `axios.get()` returns, this will keep the promise chain intact.

I would also suggest throwing in the reject handler to propagate any error to the top level, again keeping the chain intact.

```
getFirstPageData();

async function getFirstPageData() {
    try {
        const res =  await getPageData(1) ;
        console.log("res--->", res);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error);
    }
}

async function getPageData(page_num){

  let pageNum = page_num;
  console.log("page_num" , pageNum);

  let path =    "https://......"

  return axios.get(path).then(
        (response) => {
            var result = response.data;
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        },
        (error) => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In light of my comment on your post and what you are trying to do.
Your `getPageData` should return the promise from axios like the following.

```
function getPageData(page_num){

  let pageNum = page_num;
  console.log("page_num" , pageNum);

  let path =    "https://......"

  return axios.get(path).then(
    (response) => {
        var result = response.data;
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
}
```

Loose the async from the function `getPageData` since it is not an asynchronous function. it returns a promise that you will get data from in your `const res =  await getPageData(1) ;`